# multiple image upload field

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.0

Its pretty simple to add form fields for uploading files etc, but I am after one that I can highlight several files and upload them all in one field.

Is there a plugin of some sort that can allow me to do this? I cant find one, also, do v1 plugins work with v2?

I should be able to add the ability to show the files and delete them myself but if this was included it would be very nice.

Thanks.

EDIT: I am using CakePHP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with normal php code

If you use multiple input fields you can set
 `name="file[]"`. 
That will put them in an array when you upload them

```
($_FILES['file'] = array ({file_array},{file_array]..))
```

Or try

[Plugin](http://swfupload.org/)

Update: For [Cakephp](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/crux/2009/02/15/ability-to-select-and-upload-multiple-files-at-once-under-5-mins)

Answer (score 0):

Use uplodify it will allow you to upload multiple files

Refer this http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

in **HTML5** you can use like below

```
<form action='#' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input name='uploads[]' type=file multiple>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

[`html5`](http://rakaz.nl/2009/08/uploading-multiple-files-using-html5.html)
[`using PHP`](http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload)

Comment: @Jleagle.. i dont have any experice with cake PHP. i just suggest you how to use in HTMl and php

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just try using the attribute multiple="multiple" on your file input, and see how it goes. Most modern browsers support this, and those who don't would limit it to 1 file.

If you name it with brackets PHP will probably make it an array.

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" />
```